# How can I use the same checkboxes to submit multiple times to create multiple sets of selections?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to have a set of checkboxes that use AJAX to post to a PHP page, but after the post I want to be able to use the same checkboxes to send another set of selections to the same PHP page, up to a specified number of sets, and then use the sets as data in the PHP page.

I can't figure out how this would be implemented. Any ideas?

index.php:

```
<form id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="5" />
  <input type="button" id="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: $("form#checkboxes").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#div").load('success.php')
      }
    });
    })
  })
</script>
```

process.php:

```
$data = array();
foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $key => $value){
  $data[] = "$value";
}
```

Comment: Try to add some code samples of what you have tried so we can help you from there.

Comment: Then you need to use Sessions! Check out my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Sessions, if you want data to prevail over time. So, you can use it this way:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["data"]))
        $_SESSION["data"] = array();
    foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $key => $value){
      $_SESSION["data"] = "$value";
    }
    // Print out the final array, if there's a parameter final!
    if (isset($_GET["final"]))
        foreach ($_SESSION["data"] as $data)
            echo $data;
?>
```

And for the JavaScript, you need to reset the thingy:

```
<form id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="5" />
    <input type="button" id="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $("form#checkboxes").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#div").load('success.php');
                    $("form#checkboxes > input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can just use this way, replace `$_SESSION["data"]` with `$_SESSION["data"][0]`, `$_SESSION["data"][1]`, `$_SESSION["data"][2]`! And make sure that when he tries to submit it after a third time, he should be given an error message saying that only three times he can submit! Simple! :)

Comment: No no!!! Make it a counter! Initialize `$_SESSION["count"] = 0` and increment it one by one. Initialize the way I did for `$_SESSION["data"]` using the `isset()` function. :)

Comment: Have a counter inside the `<script>` tag and increment it inside the `success` function!

Answer (score 0):

You would use the success function of the ajax call. We would get the value of each checked box and then submit the form through ajax, prevent Default, and then uncheck all boxes after form submit.

```
$('something').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var checked = [];
  $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function(i,v){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      checked.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'someurl.ext',
    type: 'post',
    data: checked,
    success: function(data){
      $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function(i,v){
        $(this).prop('checked', false');
      });
    }

  });
});
```